MAUI iOS - HideSoftInputOnTapped is not working issue
I have an MAUI .NET 8 project, I am facing an issue that When I click outside the custom entry when it has focus, it won't lose focus and won't hide the soft keyboard even when I Set HideSoftInputOnTapped="True".
However, this issue will not happen if CustomRender is not implemented.
Please help me to resolve this issue.
Please find the code
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:EntryPOC"       HideSoftInputOnTapped="True"
             x:Class="EntryPOC.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout   x:Name="layout" 
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            <custom:CustomEntry Unfocused="VisualElement_OnUnfocused" Completed="CustomEntry_OnCompleted"></custom:CustomEntry>
       
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>


  public class CustomEntry   : Entry
    {
        public new event EventHandler Completed;
    
        public CustomEntry()
        {
            // Default parameter
        }
    
        public CustomEntry(string PropertyID)
        {
            ClassId = PropertyID;
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        }
    
        public const string ReturnKeyPropertyName = "ReturnKeyType";
    
    
        public static readonly BindableProperty ReturnKeyTypeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: ReturnKeyPropertyName,
            returnType: typeof(ReturnKeyTypes),
            declaringType: typeof(CustomEntry),
            defaultValue: ReturnKeyTypes.Done);
    
        public ReturnKeyTypes ReturnKeyType
        {
            get { return (ReturnKeyTypes)GetValue(ReturnKeyTypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ReturnKeyTypeProperty, value); }
        }
    
        public Constants.eKeyboardTypes KeyBoardType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    
        public void InvokeCompleted()
        {
            if (this.Completed != null)
                this.Completed.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    
        public void SetVisible()
        {
            Enable();
            IsVisible = true;
        }
    
        public void Enable()
        {
            IsEnabled = true;
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        }
    
        public void ReadOnly()
        {
            SetVisible();
            IsEnabled = false;
            BackgroundColor = Constants.ReadOnlyBackGroundColor;
        }
    
        public void Disabled()
        {
            SetVisible();
            IsEnabled = false;
            BackgroundColor = Constants.DisabledBackGroundColor;
        }
    
    }
    
    public enum ReturnKeyTypes : int
    {
        Default,
        Go,
        Google,
        Join,
        Next,
        Route,
        Search,
        Send,
        Yahoo,
        Done,
        EmergencyCall,
        Continue
    }

public class CustomEntry_IOS: EntryRenderer
{
        public CustomEntry_IOS()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            CustomEntry entry = (CustomEntry)this.Element;
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if ((Control != null) && (e.NewElement != null))
                Control.ReturnKeyType = (e.NewElement as CustomEntry).ReturnKeyType.GetValueFromDescription();
            Control.Placeholder = entry.Placeholder;
            //Control?.ResignFirstResponder();
            // Editor Action is called when the return button is pressed

            //if (entry != null && entry.Keyboard == Keyboard.Numeric)
            //{
            //    Control.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation;
            //}
            if (Control != null)
                Control.ShouldReturn += (UITextField tf) =>
                {
                    entry.InvokeCompleted();
                    return true;
                };
            if (entry != null)
            {
                SetKeybordType(entry.KeyBoardType);
            }
        }






        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
               // Control?.ResignFirstResponder();
                if (e.PropertyName == CustomEntry.ReturnKeyPropertyName)
                {

                    Control.ReturnKeyType = (sender as CustomEntry).ReturnKeyType.GetValueFromDescription();

                    //Control.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Continue;
                }
                if ((sender as CustomEntry) != null && (sender as CustomEntry).Keyboard == Keyboard.Numeric)
                {
                    Control.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.PhonePad;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              //  AppDelegate.log?.WriteLog(ex, Location: this.GetType().Name + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            }

        }

        void SetKeybordType(Constants.eKeyboardTypes keyboardType)
        {
            switch (keyboardType)
            {
                case Constants.eKeyboardTypes.Default:
                    this.Control.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default;
                    break;
                case Constants.eKeyboardTypes.Email:
                    this.Control.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress;
                    break;
                case Constants.eKeyboardTypes.Numeric:
                    this.Control.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
                    break;
                case Constants.eKeyboardTypes.NumericWithDecimal:
                    this.Control.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad;
                    break;
                case Constants.eKeyboardTypes.NumericWithMinusAndDigit:
                case Constants.eKeyboardTypes.NumericWithMinus:
                    this.Control.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation;
                    break;
                default:
                    this.Control.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static UIReturnKeyType GetValueFromDescription(this ReturnKeyTypes value)
        {
            var type = typeof(UIReturnKeyType);
            if (!type.IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            foreach (var field in type.GetFields())
            {
                var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                    typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    if (attribute.Description == value.ToString())
                        return (UIReturnKeyType)field.GetValue(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (field.Name == value.ToString())
                        return (UIReturnKeyType)field.GetValue(null);
                }
            }
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Not supported on iOS: {value}");
        }
    }


Maui uses the custom handler instead of the custom render.

Custom render is working fine.But HideSoftInputOnTapped is not working

Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example? I am affected by some of your code and have run into issues while trying to migrate EntryRenderer to EntryHandler.
